# Minor change to QComboBox's stylesheet hides dropdown arrow

Tags: qt, qcombobox, qtstylesheets

I'm messing about with stylesheets in Qt. I have a QComboBox that I have styled in QtCreator with this:

```
 QComboBox::drop-down {
     border-left-width: 1px;
     border-left-color: red;
     border-left-style: solid;
}
```

This effectively adds a small red border to my drop down, but  it also makes the drop down arrow disappear? Why is that? Do I need to add anything else?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take a look at: https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/stylesheet-examples.html#id-bcbaea83-e720-403d-b175-7dc186b83ff1

Comment: Yeah, had a look at that one, but in there they change the arrow icon to a custom one. Isn't there a way to just get the default one?

Comment: What you mean by "default one"? If you start to customize borders - than you should understand, that OS defaults are not acceptable anymore, including icons / colors / etc.